# htaccess redirect when non development domain is active

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a domain staticbackup.mydomain.com which has a static backup of the main site incase of server failure I can quickly switch the www. cname to point to staticbackup.mydomain.com (A record)

On the staticbackup I don't want the site accessible if you visit via statisbackup.mydomain.com, only if it's www.mydomain.com

Is there a way I can do this with htaccess?

This is what I have created (the site is live and I cannot test)

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    rewritecond %{http_host} ^staticbackup.mydomain.com [nc]
    rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you deny access to that domain:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staticbackup.mydomain.com [NC]
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
```